# Native heap keeps increasing

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, android-memory

First I'm using API 10.

I have activity A and activity B.

I launch activity B from A.  Then I call finish() in the oncreate() of B.  I then launch activity B from A again and so on.  When i do this my native heap keeps increasing by about .5 MB every time.

This is the only code I have in activity B.

```
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            logHeap(); //keeps track of native heap size
            setContentView(R.layout.gameplay);
            finish();
            return;
```

Are the bitmaps in layout not getting recycled?  I don't understand why my native heap size would keep increasing.

Comment: how are you creating your bitmaps?

Comment: there aren't any bitmaps created in code.  I have 1 image declared as a background in xml

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you're calling bitmap.recycle() when you no longer need the Bitmap. It may take some time for the Bitmap to be recycled by GC.

Answer (score 0):

Found most of it.

Apparently creating from assets

```
Typeface tf  = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Capture_it.ttf");
```

isn't garbage collected.

Removing it seemed to fix most of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly an answer, but a way to get an answer. If you use MAT (http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) in Eclipse and debug your app, you might find out what exactly is causing the growth in your app's native heap use.

Additionally: from Eclipse, if you access the DDMS, you might be able to use the techniques described [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#alloc) to view which objects are growing.

Comment: does MAT keep track of native heap?  There seems to be a  difference between memory and native heap for me

Comment: It's described as "The Eclipse Memory Analyzer is a fast and feature-rich Java heap analyzer that helps you find memory leaks and reduce memory consumption." so, yes.